# Updating MySQL table with PHP and checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, checkbox

I have a table called products, with an:

**id**: *int, primary key, auto increment*
**product_name**: *varchar*
**highlighted**: *int (1 or 0)*

So, I want the highlighted field to be totally updateable via my admin page, so whenever I get each product's (or row's) datas, I have a checkbox next to the product's name indicating if it's highlighted (1) or not (0).

This is my code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "usbw";
$db = "test";

mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach (isset($_POST['checkBox']) as $id => $value)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE products SET highlighted='$value' WHERE id='$id'");
}
echo "Updated! <a href='index.php'>Back</a>";
}
else
{
    echo "<form action='index.php' method='POST'>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
    while($q = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "".$q['product_name']."";
        if($q['highlighted'] == '1')
        {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' checked value='1' name='checkBox['"; ?><?php echo $q['id']; ?><?php echo "']'>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='checkBox['"; ?><?php echo $q['id']; ?><?php echo "']'>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    }

echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
}

?>
```

For some reason, I'm getting the following error whenever I try to update the forms:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\Badsector\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\teszt\index.php on line 15
```

Thanks for your assistance in advance, I'm totally confused now, I've been struggling for hours now!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
foreach (isset($_POST['checkBox']) as $id => $value)
```

to

```
foreach ($_POST['checkBox'] as $id => $value)
```

isset() returns a boolean, and `foreach` expects an array.

Also you are prone to mysql injection.

Comment: It didn't really solve my problem. Still getting the warning, and this one too:

    Notice: Undefined index: checkBox in C:\Users\Badsector\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\teszt\index.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

additionaly to what blake305 said, you need to change this:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' checked value='1' name='checkBox[]'>";
```

this will giv you an array in `$_POST['checkBox']`- unfortunately your id is gone then.

If thats necessary, you need to fetch every box explicitly:

`name='checkBox_<?php echo $q['id']; ?>`

and don't use `[]` after the name since that has some meaning in PHP: the POST result will be an array instead of a string.

add: this looks weird as well: `name='checkBox['"; ?><?php echo $q['id']; ?><?php echo "']'>`
shouldn't that be `name='checkBox[\"" . $q['id']. "\"]...`

Comment: I might be dumb but none of these worked for me. :( Maybe I failed with something... But you mentioned I should fetch every box explicitly. Didn't I just do that by grabbing an ID for each box with the name='....$q['id']' thingy? Sorry, I'm totally beginner.

Comment: assumed $id is 1, from your code, the name of the variable is i.e. `checkbox[1]`. you should retrieve it with `$_POST['checkbox[1]']` since thats the name of it. That will not work due to the special internal handling of [] in POST variable names in PHP. Just add a `var_dump[$_POST]` in the beginning of your script and look whats in the `$_POST`array.